# Using udev rules to run a script on USB insertion

Tags: linux, autorun, udev

I'm trying to set up a script to run every time I plug in a USB device. I created the file **/etc/udev/rules.d/90-local.rules** and added the following rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="sd*", SYSFS{model}=="Cruzer*", RUN+="sh /home/jesse/Documents/Scripts/cruzer.sh"
```

The problem is that when the drive is connected, nothing happens. The script, for debugging purposes, is rigged to send a notification with notify-send, which is installed and works fine from the terminal.

The path to the script is correct, as I've run that exact command in the terminal without any troubles.

Comment: Is your antivirus running? This is behavior which would trigger action from any number of AV programs. Although I'd expect a warning, if you've disabled notifications, you may not see it except in the logs. I would recommend disabling the internet, then your AV program, the trying it again.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 11.04 with no AV installed.

Comment: @zenbike: Why would adding custom udev rules trigger an antivirus program?

Comment: Starting any script on device insertion can cause false positives in an AV set to scan removable devices. Why, I don't know. That it happened to me with a factory installed script on a thumbdrive and Avira AV, I do know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

Try to copy your script into `/usr/local/bin` and change the directory in your `.rules` file.

Also, I don't know what SYSFS is, but I would prefer to use the ATTR properties.

The following line is the content of my `.rules` file:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", ATTRS{vendor}=="SanDisk ", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/backup.sh"
```

Answer (score 7):

`notify-send` requires access to your DBus session bus, which it cannot have for two reasons:

- No information about the session. When started by udev, your script knows *nothing* about where you are logged in or if you're logged in at all. Multi-seat with X11 is still tricky, but user switching works for both X11 and console sessions. Many people also use SSH, VNC and NX over the network.

  (`DISPLAY=:0` would work half of the time, but that's still *guessing* at best.)
- Denied by DBus policy. Even if your script somehow finds your X11 session, it will not be able to send notifications due to the script being run as `root` instead of your user account.

Comment: `for LINE in $(find /proc/ -maxdepth 2 -name environ -exec grep -z "^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" {} \; | sort -uz | tr '\0' '\n'); do eval $LINE   ... done;` did the trick for me with notify-send

Answer (score 1):

You can try to match the device by vendor and product IDs instead. The following custom rule works for me:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0763", ATTR{idProduct}=="019b", RUN+="/usr/bin/aconnect 20 128"
```

You can see idVendor and idProduct in the lsusb output or dmesg after attaching the device.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work either... (ATTR{idProduct}=="5530")... is the vendor also required? I wouldn't think so...

Comment: In that case the problem might be with the script itself. For example it may depend on $PATH env variable. For a test try to run it like

export PATH=''; /home/jesse/Documents/Scripts/cruzer.sh

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Aleh's answer: If you also want to monitor `remove` events, you need to look for an environment variable named `ID_SERIAL`. It contains vendor and product ID separated by underscore:

```
ACTION=="add|remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="0763_019b" RUN+="/usr/bin/aconnect 20 128"
```

The rule is now shorter, too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you may need to add a `sleep` within the script, to give the usb device a chance to "settle" down? For example, usb 3g modems, mode switching to get a /dev/ttyUSB to get kicked up and running by the kernel.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace SUBSYSTEM="usb" with SUBSYSTEMS="usb"

Comment: No, `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` is just fine.